Is it possible (or recommended?) to mix abstract base classes with Pydantic BaseModel?
In the example code below, I tried to combine abstract base classes with Pydantic. I wanted to write this code because I had an existing type Ticker which has two implementations. It can either be represented as a string or an integer value.
I later wanted to add some data classes to represent messages. It seemed intuitive to implement these using Pydantic, because these message types are closely related to some FastAPI data classes (FastAPI uses Pydantic as part of its framework).
I have my suspicions about the below design. I somewhat suspect that either the ABC approach should be used or the BaseModel approach should be used, and not both. This would also remove multiple inheritance from the design, which would likely be another benefit - for simplicity if nothing else.
If this is the case, I would prefer to keep the runtime type-checking behaviour offered by Pydantic. But in this case, I do not know how to implement a class Ticker which can have two representations - as a str and int.
The immediate problem is a runtime error:
pydantic.errors.PydanticSchemaGenerationError: Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for <class '__main__.Ticker'>. Set `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` in the model_config to ignore this error or implement `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on your type to fully support it.

If you got this error by calling handler(<some type>) within `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` then you likely need to call `handler.generate_schema(<some type>)` since we do not call `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on `<some type>` otherwise to avoid infinite recursion.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.8/u/schema-for-unknown-type

Example code:
from abc import ABC
from abc import abstractmethod

from pydantic import BaseModel


class AbstractTicker(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def to_str(self) -> str:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _get_value(self) -> str|int:
        pass


class Ticker():
    _ticker: AbstractTicker

    def __init__(self, ticker: object):
        if isinstance(ticker, str):
            self._ticker = TickerStr(ticker)
        elif isinstance(ticker, int):
            self._ticker = TickerInt(ticker)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'unsupported type {type(ticker)} for ticker')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self._ticker)

    def to_str(self) -> str:
        return self._ticker.to_str()

    def __eq__(self, ticker: object) -> bool:
        if isinstance(ticker, Ticker):
            return self._ticker._get_value() == ticker._ticker._get_value()
        return False


class TickerStr(AbstractTicker, BaseModel):
    _ticker_str: str

    def __init__(self, ticker_str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        assert isinstance(ticker_str, str), f'ticker must be of type str'
        assert len(ticker_str) > 0, f'ticker cannot be empty string'
        self._ticker_str = ticker_str

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Ticker[str]({self._ticker_str})'

    def _get_value(self) -> str:
        return self._ticker_str

    def to_str(self) -> str:
        return self._ticker_str


class TickerInt(AbstractTicker, BaseModel):
    _ticker_int: int

    def __init__(self, ticker_int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        assert isinstance(ticker_int, int), f'ticker must be of type int'
        assert ticker_int > 0, f'ticker must be > 0'
        self._ticker_int = ticker_int

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Ticker[int]({self._ticker_int})'

    def _get_value(self) -> int:
        return self._ticker_int

    def to_str(self) -> str:
        return str(self._ticker_int)


class AbstractMessage(ABC, BaseModel):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        pass


class ConcreteMessage(AbstractMessage):
    ticker: Ticker

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.ticker = Ticker('TEST')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{str(self.ticker)}'


def main():
    str_ticker = TickerStr('NVDA')
    int_ticker = TickerInt(1234)

    print(str_ticker)
    print(int_ticker)

    concrete_message = ConcreteMessage()
    print(concrete_message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

It could be that what I have tried to write in the example code is inadvisable or there might otherwise be a reason why this is a bad idea. If this is the case, please do let me know.

Is it vital to implement it using two different subclasses? See this Q&A for a possibly alternate solution.
